# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment in finding local maximum

Tags: python, tuples, max, local

```
for i in range(200): 
    maximums[i] = scipy.signal.argrelextrema(b1[i], np.greater)
```

the above code results in 'tuple' object does not support item assignment. b1 is a 2D array. I need to save the index of local maxima in each iteration, that's why I wrote maximums[i]. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but you could make `maximums` a list instead of an *immutable* tuple.

Comment: Did you using `maximums = ()` before the loop began?

Comment: How do you figure out how to use `scipy` without figuring out how to create a list? Please work through the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutables in python. So you can not assign a value to a tuple after initializing it. you can use list instead

Comment: First initialize a list 
maximums = []
then you can do whatever you want
for i in range(200): 
    maximums[i] = scipy.signal.argrelextrema(b1[i], np.greater)

Comment: I'd rather do `for i in range(200): maximums.append(scipy.signal.argrelextrema(b1[i], np.greater))`

Comment: yeah @Błotosmętek. you are right. append method will do the trick too